# Backbone.js: render only last model in collection, display total number of models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a basic backbone.js app that renders a collection of models. I would like to modify to render only the last model, and also display a number for the total number of models. Here is my code so far:

```
 var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
 });

 var ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
     template: _.template('<h3><%= title %></h3>'),

     render: function(){
         var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
         this.$el.append(this.template(attributes));
     }
 });


 var ThingsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Thing
});

var things = [
  { title: "Macbook Air", price: 799 },
  { title: "Macbook Pro", price: 999 },
  { title: "The new iPad", price: 399 },
  { title: "Magic Mouse", price: 50 },
  { title: "Cinema Display", price: 799 }
];

var thingsList = new ThingsList(things);


var ThingsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $('body'),
   render: function(){
     _.each(this.collection.models, function (things) {
            this.renderThing(things);
        }, this);
    },


  renderThing: function(things) {
    var thingView = new ThingView({ model: things }); 
    this.$el.append(thingView.render()); 
  }

});

var thingsListView = new ThingsListView( {collection: thingsList} );
thingsListView.render();
```

Answer (score 13):

Get the last model from the collection using [`at()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-at):

```
// this.collection.length - 1 is the index of the last model in the collection
var last_model = this.collection.at(this.collection.length - 1);
```

Your `render()` function would then look something like this:

```
render: function(){
    var last_model = this.collection.at(this.collection.length - 1);
    this.renderThing(last_model);
}
```

Get the total number of models in the collection using the [`length`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-length) property:

```
var total = this.collection.length;
```

Edited to add that Backbone offers a [`last()`](http://underscorejs.org/#last) method on each collection, courtesy of Underscore JS (thanks to [@RocketR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486820/rocketr) for pointing this out). So, the above could more easily be written as follows:

```
var last_model = this.collection.last();
```

Comment: Collection has a `last` method to get the last element.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the `collection.length` function but it kept on failing, but going to the basics helped:

To get the first Model I recommend:

```
var firstModel = Models.at(0);      
alert(firstModel.get("attribute"));
```

To get the last Model on the collection of Models:

```
var lastModel = Models.pop();
var lastModelId = lastModel .get("id");
```

Comment: Beware, using `pop()` will remove and return the last element from the collection. This may not be the desired behaviour.